# Get metas with simple html dom 1.5 2014 php

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am trying to get the meta description/keywords of google.com, but I end up with a null array.

```
<?php
include "simple_html_dom.php";
$url = isset($_POST['url']) ? $_POST['url'] : ''; // this would be http://www.google.com
if(!empty($url) && @file_get_contents($url) == true) {
    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $html->load_file($url); //put url or filename in place of xxx
    $title = $html->find('title', 0)->plaintext;
    //echo $title;

    $descr = $html->find("meta[name='description']", 0);
    var_dump($descr); // NULL

}
?>
```

the `$title` is being get ok, but the description is a problem and don't understand why.
I also tried

```
$descr = $html->find("meta[name='description']", 0)->content;
```

results in `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object`

or

```
$descr = $html->find("meta[name='description']", 0)->attr('content');
```

results in `Fatal error: Call to a member function attr() on a non-object`

or

```
 $descr = $html->find("meta[name='description']", 0)->getAttribute('content');
```

results in `Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttribute() on a non-object`.

All those errors I believe that they are because meta description cannot be found, despite the fact if you turn on to view source code on Google.com you will see that is the first thing you see after head tag
Please help me on this I am a noob in Simple HTML DOM. It's much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you what you want:

```
<?php
include "simple_html_dom.php";
$url = isset($_POST['url']) ? $_POST['url'] : ''; // this would be http://www.google.com
if(!empty($url)) {
    $html = file_get_html($url);
    $title = $html->find('title', 0)->plaintext;
    echo $title . "\n";;

    $descr = $html->find("meta[name='description']", 0);
    echo $descr . "\n";
```

}
   ?>

Output is

```
Google
<meta content="Search the world's information, including webpages, images, videos and more. Google has many special features to help you find exactly what you're looking for." name="description">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Keywords like this:

```
$oHTML = str_get_html( $remote_html );
$arElements = $oHTML->find( "meta[name=keywords]" );
echo $arElements[0]->content;
```

Comment: not working, not even the keywords. I get `Notice: Undefined offset: 0` + `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: Can you parse the rest of the HTML file (Titles, Divs...)? or does this also give errors?

Comment: If I do an `echo $html;` after `$html->load_file($url);` I can see the webpage. It seams that it works only for the title, title is getting parsed.

Comment: The rest of the elements seams that they are not getting found.